# client certificate in downloadmanager api

Tags: android, flutter, api, kotlin, client-certificates

I have a flutter app that uses Kotlin to call the DownloadManager API and download the file from my URL. But my website uses client certificate authentication. I have the certificate. How can I load the certificate with the DownloadManager API?

Comment: Can you please add what type of certificates needs to be added? Do you mean a TLS certificate?

Comment: @DarshShah the certificate is a ssl certificate a .pfx file.